# What does the memory location src contain after executing memmove(void *dst,const void *src,size_t len)?

Tags: c

After the memmove() function executes what would be the value stored in the memory location where src points to ?

Comment: See [ask], provide a [mcve]. What is your **specific** problem? How `memmove` works is versy clearly detailed in its documentation. Reading the man-page should help.

Comment: It contains the unmodified `src`, unless source and destination overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `memmove` as two `memcpy` operations.

```
char temp[len];
memcpy(temp, src, len);
memcpy(dst, temp, len):
```

If source and destination don't overlap, there is no change to source.

If they overlap, then the values in the overlapped region will change.